# Search for specific folder in library with CAML

Tags: document-library, caml-query, folder, caml

I'm looking for a way to search for folder which name starts of 'Foo' using caml query in list. How can I narrow results to return only folders?

Answer (score 3):

you can filter on folder content type

try this

```
// Source data retriever
SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();
// Table to hold retrieved information
DataTable dt = null;

// Set data retrieve settigns
query.Lists = "<Lists BaseType='1'/>";
query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"Recursive\" />";
query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"" + Fields.Title + "\" />" + "" +
"<FieldRef Name=\"Name\" />" + "" +
"<FieldRef Name=\"Fileref\" />" + "" +
"\" />";

query.Query = CamlQuery;
dt = web.GetSiteData(query);

if (dt != null)
{
   foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
   {
      // Do your job
   }
}
```

And CAML query:

```
   <Where>
      <And>
         <BeginsWith>
            <FieldRef Name='ContentType' />
            <Value Type='Computed'>Folder</Value>
         </BeginsWith>
         <BeginsWith>
            <FieldRef Name='Title' />
            <Value Type='Text'>Foo</Value>
         </BeginsWith>
      </And>
   </Where>
```

[Here is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms452896%28v=office.14%29.aspx) a MSDN source for content types ids.

Hope it helps,

Andrew