# Can we query and fetch data from LIST between different subsites using CAML Query.?

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, caml-query, caml

Have LIST created under one site, can the same LIST be used to fetch data from other site using CAML Query.?

eg:

Consider a LIST "xxx" created under SitePages/AAA/Lists/

Can i access the LIST "xxx" from other site i.e SitePages/BBB/

To Summarize, Is it possible to access the LIST across parent and child sites, vice-versa.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can perform a search of list by specifying its content type or/and ID or something similar to identify your list from the root web. If do a recursiv search there will be your list item returned from the web. After you need to just open a list using API.

[See this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/64905/search-for-specific-folder-in-library-with-caml/64908#64908) post for the code.

Hope it helps,

Andrew